# How is it possible to resolve unresolved symbols (LNK2001) for _RTC_InitData and _RTC_Shutdown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build, linker

I am building an x64 lib in Visual Studio 2008, and separately linking it into an x64 DLL (specifically using the WDK Build.exe toolchain in this case). Most general C runtime symbols link fine, indicating that the library versions are sufficiently well-matched, but these two RTC_* symbols specifically fail. Forcing different runtime library versions, as well as aggressive symbol includes in the linker options for the lib does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These `RTC_*` symbols are mentioned several places on Google, but are not well-documented. They are entrypoints used by the new Runtime Check (RTC) functionality of the VC9 compiler. Disabling runtime checks in `[Project Property Pages] > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation` by setting `Basic Runtime Checks` from `Both (/RTC1, equiv. to /RTCsu)` to `Default`.